# Getting n rows from resultset of select query on a postgres postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, get

I am adding pagination in a get API, and need to get specific row numbers from a select query. How can I achieve this in postgresql?
Like for page=2 and count=10, I want to retrieve rows 11-20.

```
select users.id from users, usernotification where usernotification.channel=1 and usernotification.id=users.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres has no inherent concept of row numbers. True row numbers may be created, but unless you store them, it will be on a query-by-query basis. That said, the following requires keeping track on only the page number to display. It also has the advantage handling both forward and backward scrolling.

**NOTE:** I have modified your query to use Standard ANSI join syntax. You should adopt it. It is much easier to see what is actually desired and less error prone.

```
   select u.id 
     from users u
     join usernotification un 
       on un.id = u.id and un.channel=1
    order by u.id 
   offset (&page_num-1) * 10 limit 10;
```

A disadvantage it may be subject to "missing" rows if other users delete a previously displayed row. If so you will "miss" the number of subsequent rows equal to the number of rows deleted. For example while displaying rows 1-10 another user deletes 5 of them, your page 2 will display the original rows 15-24, not 11-20.  
See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=84930f2d076ad4e95ac86db584be9b96). Since db<>fiddle does not support paging it will 'page forward' with an a-prior knowledge page controlling value. Also added a couple additional columns.